# Appcelerator + Alloy + Eval to Loop through Objects - $ breaks it

Tags: javascript, loops, runtime-error, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have 384 objects on screen that I need to iterate through in a specific order, changing their properties according to a changing variable. Here's what the objects look like in the .xml file:

```
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res1_1" class="resBit" left="1.5%" bottom="25.0%" />
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res1_2" class="resBit" left="1.5%" bottom="27.3%" />
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res1_3" class="resBit" left="1.5%" bottom="29.6%" />
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res1_4" class="resBit" left="1.5%" bottom="31.9%" />
    [...]
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res16_22" class="resBit" left="93.0%" bottom="73.3%" />
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res16_23" class="resBit" left="93.0%" bottom="75.6%" />
    <View formFactor="tablet" id="res16_24" class="resBit" left="93.0%" bottom="77.9%" />
```

This is what the javascript looks like:

```
// theValues rotates between a set of 100 or so such combinations
theValues = "2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3".split(",");

// Start on the left and move right
for (i=1; i<17; i++) {
    // Start at the bottom and move up
    for (ii=1; ii<25; ii++) {
        if (ii < (theValues[i-1]) - 1) {
            // Make first row solid
            if (i == 1) { eval('$.res' + i + '_' + ii + '.setOpacity(1);'); }
            // Paint reds
            eval('$.res' + i + '_' + ii + '.setBackgroundColor("red");');
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [10567,152803] ----- Titanium Javascript Runtime Error -----
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,152803] - In undefined:1,1
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [0,152803] - Message: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
[ERROR] :  TiExceptionHandler: (main) [1,152804] - Source: $.res1_1.setOpacity(1);
```

If I just write `$.res1_1.setOpacity(1);` directly in the code, it works. It's the eval that breaks it. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: havent used appcelerator in a while but i think you can do it like this `if (i == 1) { $['res' + i + '_' + ii].setOpacity(1); }`

Comment: That worked! Please add it as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Comment: just upvote the comment, thats fine :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that you need to take care about other than that error.

First thing is to overhaul your UI structure. Currently it's not recommended to set left/bottom/top/right properties manually when you can really use layout types to create your views properly.

From the looks of your XML code, it seems you are creating a grid-view of **16 columns x 25 rows** with each view having a **left padding of 1.5% & top padding of 2.3% (here you have given it as bottom)** The main issue with how you are currently designing it is using the left/bottom properties manually **AND** of course **Why on earth someone would create 384 views manually :)** .. It would take a great patience to do so & at least I do not have it :)

Now the recommended way to create such UI is something like this:

**template.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="resBit" left="1.5%" top="2.3%" />
</Alloy>
```

**your_view.xml**

```
<View id='parentContainer' formFactor="tablet" layout='horizontal' horizontalWrap='true' right='1.5%'>
    ..... here comes your those resBit views created dynamically
    // formFactor property is only set to parent container which also applies to its child container, so no need to set it on all 384 child views as you did

    // horizontalWrap property ensures that child-views which are going out of bound, will be created in
    // next row & thus it creates a grid-view automatically while using proper sizes so the last or
    // 16th view fits to the end of parent view.
</View>
```

**your_view.js**

```
// create child-views dynamically like this
for (var i=1; i<=384; i++) {
    // you can pass any required arguments here needed to create child-views
    var templateView = Alloy.createController('template', {
        position : i
    }).getView();

    $.parentContainer.add(templateView);
}
```

**template.js**

```
var pos = $.args.position;

// if it's the last or 16th child-view in each row, then set its width to fill the parent width, which will make sure that your next child-view will move to a new row.
// it's necessary because sometimes while using %age dimensions, there might be a few pixels calculation error which can create the 16th child-view to next row

if ((pos % 16) == 0) {
    $.template.width = Ti.UI.FILL;
}
```

**Finally**, since you do not have ids as res12_14, etc. you can still access all your child-views like this:

**your_view.js**

```
// theValues rotates between a set of 100 or so such combinations
theValues = "2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3,2,2,3,4,5,5,4,3".split(",");

// gives you all child-views in an array
var child_views = $.parentContainer.children;

// Start on the left and move right
for (i=1; i<17; i++) {

    // Start at the bottom and move up
    for (ii=1; ii<25; ii++) {
        if (ii < (theValues[i-1]) - 1) {
            var currentChildPos = i * ii - 1;       // since we started loop from 1 & array index starts from 0
            // Make first row solid
            if (i == 1) {
                child_views[currentChildPos].setOpacity(1);
            }

            // Paint reds
            child_views[currentChildPos].setBackgroundColor("red");
        }
    }
}
```

This is how you should truly use the **Alloy MVC framework**, write less-code, write more maintainable code. If you need to make any change in those resBit views, then you can make it now in **template.xml** file instead of at 384 places in your previous code.

Comment: Interesting take on the situation. Thanks for the insight. 